# Possible to rename "sales" and "customers" into "remedy" and "patient"?

Tags: customer-portal, custom, customization, partner-portal, theme-branding

I am interested in using Salesforce (or something like it) to help identify what a patient needs and solve them using holistic tools and techniques.

In order to effectively do this, I want to remove all aspect of "sales" from the portal, because a sales-oriented mindset will remove effectiveness of the solution I'm working on. (I only want suitability for fit, and if my product doesn't fit their needs, I don't want me or my team to sell it to them)

Does salesforce allow for renaming of all menu fields, and potentially removing the word "sales" from all aspects of the GUI, including the URL, to support a specific bespoke offering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use custom domains, custom branding, and rename standard objects, fields, and tabs. You'll want to do some research on this, as it'll take a bit to set everything up.